# Online SQL Login - Visual Basic 2008

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

I have here a simple question for those expertise out there (but please explain well, I'm very new). I made a visual basic 2008 application that allows you to login from a database. I followed this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0dcPiLYrck

But the problem is that I have to keep debugging my app if I make a new user. Is their a way where I can upload my information through the internet and the application can pick it up from there? Also in my bin/release folder I get 2 sql files, how would I get rid of these but still be able to connect?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: The answer to this question would stretch many pages.  I suggest you pick up an introduction to ASP.NET programming like this http://www.amazon.com/Murachs-ASP-NET-Web-Programming-VB-NET/dp/1890774200/ref=pd_sim_b_3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about a desktop application or a web application here. But to answer the question about making a new user, if you go by the video (which is desktop development) you will need to make a new form that will insert a username and password into the database. You don't always need to have the application running in debug mode. You can find the file folder that this application was created in and find the .exe that was created and execute the application from that.

I'm not sure what you'r talking about with the SQL files. If they have the extension of .mdb and mdf, then yes you will need those files because that is your physical database.

For more information about desktop development you can check out [Microsoft's Beginer Devloper Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/dd435692.aspx). At that website you should be able to find all kinds of tutorials, walk throughs and examples of how to create desktop applications much like you saw in the youtube video.

Good luck and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same thing. Unfortunately, i don't believe that is easy to make a thing like this, especially for a newbie like me XD But maybe you can ask directly to the autor of the video, he of course know very well the databases of Visualbasic. Bye!